# Requiring an objectly array in JavaScript

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

Consider an example challenge:

> Given a number `b` and an array `a`, output the `b`th element of the array `a`.

In this case, when requiring input in JavaScript, we need an array and a number as input.

The usual (accepted) function input method are `(a,b)=>a[b]` or `a=>b=>a[b]`, but can I require to input the array `a` with extra property `b`, which is constructed by

```
a=[1,2,3]; a.b=2;
```

and the submission is `a=>a[a.b]` ?

If that's allowed, does it increase the byte-count?

Answer (score 3):

## No

The example challenge requires "an array" and "a number". The "modified array" is not strictly an array.

However, passing a dictionary-like object (`{a: [1, 2, 3], b: 2}`) is valid.

Comment: Is `f({a:[1,2,3],b:2})` explicitly allowed? Is `f({'for(i in x)if(i!="b")c=i;x[c][x.b]':[1,2,3],b:2})` explicitly banned as a loophole?

Comment: @l4m2 I think that's requiring more input than necessary.